# How to read characters in the middle of a String using a pointer?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I've been at this for a while and could really use some help. I'm making a password program and one of the functions test if a character between the beginning and end has a middle uppercase letter.  This is what I have tried:

```
int hasMiddleUpper(char *pass)   {
  int test=0, testu=0, testl=0, count;
  char c;

  while (c = *pass++)  {
    test++;
  }
  pass = pass - test + 1;

  while (c = *pass++)  {
    if ( isupper( c ))  {
      testu=1;
    }
  }
  pass--;

  while (c = *pass++) {
    if ( isupper(c )) {
      testl=2;
    }
  }
  count = testu + testl;

  if (count==1) {
    return 1;
  }
  else  {
    return 0;
  }

}



int pwstrength( char *pass ) 
{
  int test, test1,test2, test3, result;
  test= hasUpperAndLower( pass );
  test1 = hasAlphaDigits(pass);
  test2 = hasEightOrMore(pass);
  test3 = hasMiddleUpper(pass);
  result = test + test1 + test2 + test3;
  return result;
}

int main( void ) {
  int a;
  char *p= "Pass3wordD";
  a= pwstrength( p );
  printf( "%d \n", a );
  system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: The problem I have is that it reads the end character which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are trying to do? `How to read characters in the middle of a String using a pointer?` isn't much of a question... which letters are you trying to read? What are you doing with them? What do you call the "middle" of the string?

Comment: ..also, y u no indent?

Comment: In my main function at the bottom, I'm reading the pointer that goes to  "PAss3wordD" is what I am reading and I have to test the strength of it using 6 different functions each which return true for a maximum of strength 6.  I was just having trouble on this particular one.

Comment: This code is just... confusing as hell. Why not work on clearing it up and using indices to access the password instead of playing around with pointers and doing it poorly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int hasMiddleUpper(char *pass)
{
   char c;
   if ( ! (pass && *pass) ) return 0;

   while (c = *(++pass)) // dont test first
   {
      if (isupper(c) && *(pass+1) )  return 1; // only if not the last
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Is this what you need?

But, do you have to use pointers? With index could be simpler.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thanks a lot, I don't know what I was trying to do.

Comment: Also I would have to insist that you pass the function the string as a `cont char*` then use a pointer local to the function to iterate over the string. This will make it work for more cases.